# How can i implement signup facility in shopify store?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I was found in shopify wiki docs but dont know how to implement signup.

Comment: i was try about webhook implement with shopify api but i did not understand from this shopfiy webhook

Comment: If you have coded something, edit your question and add it - you are more likely to get help if people can see what you have tried.

Comment: please give me any link that gives shopify signup work step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From your Shopify admin, click Online Store, then click Themes (or press G W T):
2. Find the theme you want to edit, click the ... button,
3. then click Edit HTML/CSS: Click the Templates folder to expand and view its contents. Under the Templates folder, click on customers/register.liquid.
4. In customers/register.liquid, locate the following code:

{% form 'create_customer' %}

Add the form fields between that code, and this one:

{% endform %}

To add a text field, use this:

The text shown as label in the form

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

did you get a chance to have a look at [shopify_app GitHub repo](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app)